# PHP `getEnv` is able to read System Environment Variable

Tags: php, apache, docker

I have a docker container where I have setup PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4 on top of Alpine. In my PHP code I am using `getEnv` to read the Environment Variable that I am passing from Host Machine as part of docker compose file. It seem that I can read the environment variable. Maybe my understanding is wrong but I thought I would need to use [passenv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) in my Apache Virtual Host Configuration or I should add it in `envvars` file and get that loaded by Apache. Any idea why this works?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: image1
    environment:
      - HOST
```

Inside the container when I run `Env` I can see `HOST=192.168.1.1`. In the PHP code I am using `getEnv('HOST')` and that works. This question is not how to get it working as it works :) but more like why it works

Comment: Code, please. What variable are you trying to read?

Comment: Added code, hope that helps

Comment: Try another var. Let say, `- FOO=BAR`

Answer (score 0):

After doing further research on the issue. I think maybe I know why. The `env` Apache Module is meant for passing environment variables to CGI and SSI Pages. Since for CGI and SSI, Apache spawn a separate process we need the `env` module to pass environment variable to the newly created process. In the case of Apache PHP Module, the same is not happening. In Apache PHP Module, Apache uses an embedded interpreter to process the php files. Since it is the same Apache process all environment variable available in the Host machine is available to the process.

1. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html
2. https://blog.layershift.com/which-php-mode-apache-vs-cgi-vs-fastcgi/